# InvalidDefinitionException with jackson-datatype-jsr310 version 2.12.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind, jsr310

I'm having an issue with the jackson jsr310 datatype using version > 2.12.0, while this works perfectly with version 2.11.4.

This is my POJO:

```java
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Pojo {
    OffsetDateTime aDateTime;

    public OffsetDateTime getaDateTime() {
        return aDateTime;
    }

    public void setaDateTime(OffsetDateTime aDateTime) {
        this.aDateTime = aDateTime;
    }
}
```

The spring application:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OffsetTimeTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OffsetTimeTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    public OffsetTimeTestApplication() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setaDateTime(Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        try {
            mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Relevant section from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.3'
    runtimeOnly group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.12.3'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.enervalis.offsettimetest.Pojo["aDateTime"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnsupportedTypeSerializer.serialize(UnsupportedTypeSerializer.java:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4487)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3742)
    at com.enervalis.offsettimetest.OffsetTimeTestApplication.<init>(OffsetTimeTestApplication.java:24)
    at com.enervalis.offsettimetest.OffsetTimeTestApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f83afa20.<init>(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at com.enervalis.offsettimetest.OffsetTimeTestApplication.main(OffsetTimeTestApplication.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Changing the version in the build file from 2.12.3 to 2.11.4 the code runs without error.

Is there anything missing?

This works perfectly well with version 2.11.4 and lower.

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved.

Apparently, by adding the dependency, but not registering the JavaTimeModule, the OffsetDateTime gets serialized as a POJO in older versions. In the > 2.11.4 version th eException is thrown.

The JavaTimeModule must be added to the ObjectMapper:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();
```